# Is not setting an attribute to equal a value valid HTML?

Tags: html, markup

Is this line of code technically valid?

```
<img src="img.png" alt>
```

Within the CMS we are using, the devs said that they **cannot** make `alt` attributes appear on the page empty (e.g.: `alt=""`), they can either display them as the example above or they can add a space as a value (e.g.: `alt=" "`).

From what I understand, adding a space as a value could still cause some screen readers to not ignore decorative images creating accessibility issues. When I preview the above example in browsers, it does appear correct in dev tools and passes an HTML validator, but it just seems like it may be wrong or sloppy markup.

Is this valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's valid. `alt=""` or just `alt` is recommended if you have purely decorative images, so screenreaders won't read irrelevant info like "red dot".

See also the "alt"-Paragraph on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I wasn't sure if just having alt was the same as alt="".

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is valid html5 spec, but not xhtml. You don't have to trust me though, use the [w3c validator](https://validator.w3.org/).